# Parse INI file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, fs, ini

I build a Node.js tool in order to change GCP config quickly. But I'm a bit stuck on the parsing of the `config_nameOfConfig` file.
It looks like this :

```
[core]
account = email@example.fr
project = project-example
disable_usage_reporting = False

[compute]
region = europe-west1-b
```

(This file is available in `'/Users/nameOfUser/.config/gcloud'`)

And I want to convert it in an object like this :

```
const config = {
  account:"email@example.fr",
  project:"project-example",
  disable_usage_reporting:false,
  region:"europe-west1-b",
};
```

I get the content of this file with the `fs.readFileSync` function who converts it into a string.

An idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an ini file format. Unless you want to do the parsing yourself, you'd better just download a library to your project, for example:

```
npm install ini
```

Then in the code:

```
var ini = require('ini')
var fs = require('fs')
var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config_nameOfConfig', 'utf-8'))
```

In `config` you should now have object containing the data in the file.
You can `console.log(config)` to see how it exactly looks like.